# Laravel: extend a file in parent folder from subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, view

i want to extend the master.blade.php located in views\backend folder.

view/backend/master.blade.php <--i want to extend this file

view/backend/partials/header.blade.php <--the file that will extend the master.blade.php

**folder structure**

- views

  - backend

    -master.blade.php

    - partials

      -header.blade.php

      -footer.blade.php

      -sidebar.blade.php

I tried this in the header.blade.php file but fail:

```
@extends('backend.master')
```

Edited
**master.blade.php**

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        @yield('header')
        @yield('sidebar')
        @yield('content')
        @yield('footer')
    </div>
  </body>
```

**header.blade.php**

```
@extends('backend.master')

@section('header')
<p> this is the header</p>
@endsection
```

The page shows master content only in the browser

Comment: please write part of your error...

Comment: Can you show us how you are rendering the template ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally **header**, **footer** and **sidebar** contain the markup which remain common across pages. Only the **content** varies from page to page.

Also the concept of extending **master** layout is to avoid repeating the shared parts across various pages. Using `@yield('header')` `@yield('footer')`
`@yield('sidebar')` defeats the concept of extending **master** layout. Because then all those sections need to be included on all pages.

So you master layout should be like

```php
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        @include('backend.partials.header')
        @include('backend.partials.sidebar')
        @yield('content')
        @include('backend.partials.footer')
    </div>
</body>
```

Then for any page you can extend the **master** layout as

```
@extends('backend.master')

@section('content')

<!-- content markup here -->

@endsection
```

Comment: i tried your suggestions, but content was was missing when viewed in browser

Comment: What do you mean? Please post the contents of the blade view you are trying to view in the browser

Comment: the content is simple html, i think this might be version issue, i want to upgrade from laravel 7 to 8

Comment: @Smith I don't think it could be  version issue. `@yield` and `@section` directives have been since long before Laravel 7. Small correction was missing the `backend.` in the `@extends` which I have update now - please check whether you didn't miss that. Without seeing the code for the blade view I can't guess what's the issue

Comment: i figured out the solution, in my controller i was doing this `backend.master` instead of this `backend.homepage`